# don't getting correct volume of a sphere from my C code?

Tags: c

I have just started learning c programming.I have a question.

I wanna  calculate the volume of a sphere from radius.my code is:

[image]

but it is not giving me correct ans for 1523.result is 14797486080.000
but the correct ans will be 14797486501.627.Where is the problem?

I found the problem here https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1011

Comment: Please don't post images. Post the code directly by copy-pasting and then formatting it as code using CTRL+K. As for the answer, try using a `double` instead of a `float`

Comment: The problem is likely the float precision. You need to look at a C programming book or tutorial. Regarding the technical description: [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to read the radius as a float using %f, rather than int and %d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation is performed in `double` and converted on assignment to `float`, so you loose precision. You probably just should declare `q` as `double`.

Also if you are really concerned about precision, you should use a better approximation of π.

Comment: For the 'desired result', the approximation of pi as 3.14159 is spot on. Using a better pi, the result would be 14797499000.5. As this is an exercise of some kind, its author went for repeatability of the result, rather than exactness.

Answer (score 1):

If you want better precision in the result, try double instead of float. A 32 bit float will give you a precision of about 7 digits. A 64 bit double will give you a precision of about 15 digits.

Comment: No, wrong. All the computations we see here are performed in `double`.

Comment: The computations are performed in double, but the presentation of the resulting variable q in printf is only presenting a float with 32 bit precision.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just should declare q as double.                                         you should use a better approximation of π.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    double volume;
    printf("Enter the radius of a sphere: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    volume=(4.0/3) *3.14159*pow(a,3);
    printf("Volume of a sphere is: %3f", volume);
    return 0;
}
```